# jQuery if... height() not working on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I'm using this code to make the left column match the right column's height if left column is shorter than right column. It works on Chrome and Firefox, and on Safari, if seem to ignore the if statement and just execute the code anyway.

```
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        var rightHeight = $('.rightcolumn').height();
        var leftHeight = $('.leftcolumn').height();
        if (leftHeight < rightHeight) {
            $('.leftcolumn').height(rightHeight);
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Safari won't just ignore an `if` statement. More likely the height is calculated differently. Have you debugged at all to see what the heights are?

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log("left: " + leftHeight + " right: " + rightHeight);` to see what the values actually are?

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rightHeight = $('.rightcolumn').height();
    var leftHeight = $('.leftcolumn').height();
    if(leftHeight < rightHeight) {
        $('.leftcolumn').height(rightHeight);
    } 
});
```

Seems to do the trick for safari. 
[**See this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p0070zb4/)